# XPath to prepend string to each returned string?

Tags: html, xml, url, xpath

I'm trying to work with XPath.  I am using an XPath tool in which I do not have the ability to programmatically resolve this issue and hope there is simply an XPath syntax to deal with this.

I have an XPath like this: `//article/x:div[2]/x:div[1]/x:h1/x:a/@href`

which of course lists out all the URLs of the matching elements.
What I do need to do is append the domain name to the front of each listed match as the returned url is relative.

I've tried `concat()` but it says syntax is wrong or it only gives me the first match.  I need it to return each match with the appended domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

You're out of luck if you cannot further process the returned list of strings.

### XPath 2.0

Append `/concat('domain', .)` to the end of your XPath to prepend `'domain'` to each result.

Comment: would it look like this? im kind of new to xpath. :)  //article/x:div[2]/x:div[1]/x:h1/x:a/@href/concat('domain', .)

Comment: Yes, but it'll only work if XPath 2.0 is supported and if your base XPath is returning the list of strings that you want.